# What is an "atomic unit of data"?

Tags: meteor

I'm working on understanding Meteor's Deps.Dependency tools.  In the docs, it says:

> A Dependency represents an atomic unit of reactive data that a
>   computation might depend on.

To see this in context, [go here](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_dependency).

I've looked around for a definition of "atomic unit of data", and I can't find a definition for it.  Does anyone know exactly what it means?  A "unit of data" makes sense - I suppose I'm trying to understand what characteristics are assumed for the word "atomic" to be included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atomic (once upon a time) meant "can not be split into smaller pieces". Since then, we've learned to split the atom, so the analogies to chemistry don't really hold.

Nevertheless, an atomic unit of data is one that can't (sensibly) be broken down into smaller parts. What constitutes a "smaller part" is enormously subjective of course. Is an integer atomic? What if I broke it down into the bytes used to represent it in memory? How about I break those bytes further into bits? You can see how this gets tedious quickly.

For your purposes, I'd consider any value stored in a cell in a database table to be atomic.

Comment: Thank you.  Nice explanation.  I've seen references to it around so it was getting annoying not to be sure of the definition.

Answer (score 2):

I'm by no means an expert on Meteor having never actually used it. I've just a passing interest in current frameworks and like to know what they are about.

Meteor is built around a sort of MVC pattern. Whenever data in the model changes changes, all generalized views get updated. By generalized I mean that the view needs not be a UI element.

This is achieved by the `Deps.Dependency` object. In the example in your link the `weather` object is "guarded" by the `weatherDep` dependency.

When the weather changes the dependency is fired and all the views relying on the weather information are recomputed/rendered.

In this case weather is considered an atomic unit of data.

Now in the example weather is a single string but the same principle applies even if weather were to contain several pieces of information; say precipitation and temperature.

So what is an atomic unit of data?

Whatever the creator of the data model deems it to be.

For the example above, say you have a weather widget on your page. This widget consumes the weather data and creates an image with a graphic representation of the weather (clouds, rain, sun, etc.) and the temperature on one corner. For this widget weather is an atomic unit of data, if any of the pieces of information that constitute the weather change, the whole widget needs to be redrawn.

A second widget may for example display only the temperature. You can have this widget depend on the weather data, but that means it will be recomputed even if only the precipitation changes, so you might decide to have two dependencies; one for the whole weather object and one for the temperature. In one case weather is the atomic unit of data and in the other it is the temperature.

In this case you'll need two sets of functions so the temperature widget calls `depends()` on the right dependency.

The amended code:

```
var weather = {precipitation:0.5, temperature:20};
var weatherDep = new Deps.Dependency;
var temperatureDep = new Deps.Dependency;

var getWeather = function () {
  weatherDep.depend()
  return weather;
};

var getTemperature = function () {
  temperatureDep.depend()
  return weather;
};


var setWeather = function (w) {
  weather = w;
  // (could add logic here to only call changed()
  // if the new value is different from the old)
  weatherDep.changed();
  temperatureDep.changed();
};

var setTemperature = function (t) {
  weather.temperature = t;
  // (could add logic here to only call changed()
  // if the new value is different from the old)
  temperatureDep.changed();
};
```

The documentation in your link says as much, I hope my explanation is clearer.